# Paginated view pages in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular5, angular7

I am trying to display an array of objects as Word document view pages using ngFor. To do that, I have prepared a temporary object and it is working fine and I am able to display it as pages based on content count.

```
  var newPageContentLength = 0;
    var pageNo = 1;
    var pageObj = {
      page: `page${pageNo}`,
      data: []
    };
    let temp = [];
    this.contentViewArray = [];
    temp.forEach((item, i) => {
        newPageContentLength += item.content.length;
      if (i == 0) {
          pageObj.data.push({ ...item, ischecked: true });
        } else {
        if (newPageContentLength < 200) {
            pageObj.data.push({ ...item, ischecked: true });
          } else {
              this.contentViewArray.push({ ...pageObj });
            pageNo += 1;
            pageObj = {
              page: `page${pageNo}`,
              data: [{ ...item, ischecked: true }]
            };
            newPageContentLength = item.content.length;
          }
        }
      if (i == temp.length - 1) {
            this.contentViewArray.push({ ...pageObj });
        }

    });
```

Using this logic i am able to create page nos if my content length is more than 200, but problem is if object is having content length more than 200, ex(if count is 240) i want that 40 words in next page.

I got stuck in breaking this 40 words into second page.

Else all are working fine.

stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vgleb3?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts